# JAVA Get and Post Requests

Tags: java, oop, http

I JUST! started learning Java after learning quite a bit of PHP (with close to Zero OOP experience but with an basic understanding of OOP however). I was looking at sample code for making a HTTP get and post requests in Java and can't understand the syntax in some of the lines.

Below is the example code I found on http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

**HttpURLConnectionExample.java**

```
package com.mkyong;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class HttpURLConnectionExample {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HttpURLConnectionExample http = new HttpURLConnectionExample();

        System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
        http.sendGet();

        System.out.println("\nTesting 2 - Send Http POST request");
        http.sendPost();

    }

    // HTTP GET request
    private void sendGet() throws Exception {

        String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=mkyong";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

    // HTTP POST request
    private void sendPost() throws Exception {

        String url = "https://selfsolve.apple.com/wcResults.do";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = "sn=C02G8416DRJM&cn=&locale=&caller=&num=12345";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

}
```

I cant understand the following in the main function

1)

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
```

What is the (HttpURLConnection)  doing before the open connection function on obj is called. I cant figure out whats it means. Where should I read to understand further.

2)

```
    HttpURLConnectionExample http = new HttpURLConnectionExample();
```

Seems to create an instance of a class with in the same class. Why ? What is this concept called ? What/Where should I read to understand this ?

3) Why are sendGet and sendPost functions called in the main function if they are not declared before main ? Shouldn't that ideally throw an error on the lines of  'function not defined '

Comment: *"I JUST! started learning Java"* followed by *"I was looking at sample code for making a HTTP get and post requests in Java"* is a complete contradiction. First actually learn Java, then start running. No wonder you don't understand.

Comment: @Gimby : I beg to differ.  Unless the asker is absolutely new to programming, it doesn't make a contradiction. HTTP get and post aren't really the most advanced topics for any student. I use AJAX aplenty in web pages.  I do not write my own classes in VBA or PHP but I do understand the OOP paradigm. For example while calling a string function on a string, it does strike me that the string function is a member function of a core class for strings. This understanding is enough for the sample code I found to not look like green or Latin to me both of which I don't understand.

Comment: @Gimby : I take your point, you would expect that people read " A complete reference " sort of book on java , page by page and cover to cover and then write their programs. Well, that is an ideal expectation from a professional programmer but I am not a professional . Also I did not run that program. Just read it and could make a fair amount of  sense of it. Not an unfair approach if  "Everyone must learn to code" even the likes of lawyers, bankers, surgeons or finance analysts..

Comment: I don't expect anything other than that people give themselves the time to learn how to walk before they start to run. If you don't you run a great risk of asking questions which get closed for numerous reasons. Asking three questions in one go where each individual question has a great risk of being a duplicate for example, is a good way to get a closed question. Just a heads up, I can't persuade you to stop looking at random code and start studying a quality source of information.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> HttpURLConnectionExample http = new HttpURLConnectionExample();
> ```

you need to create a object of a class to access its non-static methods.  so to run sendGet, sendPost you need object of the class.

"Why are sendGet and sendPost functions called in the main function if they are not declared before main ? Shouldn't that ideally throw an error on the lines of 'function not defined '"

--> In C method needs to be declared before calling method on in java however.

Answer (score 0):

1) This is a cast. Since Java is typesafe, you sometimes need to explicitly tell the compiler what type of object you are dealing with.
https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-cast/

2) That happens because the "main" method is "static". And it can't access non-static instance fields and methods. 
So the usual trick is to construct the object in the main method and call some "run" function on it (in this case "sendGet")
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

3) That is not a problem in Java. The order in which you define methods and variables within a class doesn't matter. The order does matter within methods, though.

May I suggest the Java tutorial. It's a pretty good basis and you'll understand everything in the code fragment after you've completed it:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/